# How can I keep my face cool while on the move?

Tags: temperature, walking

On those hot summer days it can be really hard to keep your face cool while on the go. You can buy portable hand fans, but carrying it around is a real hassle. What can I do to keep my face cool while on the go?

Comment: You could walk faster. You could also do nothing and you will acclimate, as long as you stay out of AC. It worked for the past tens of thousands of years, and our physiological ability to adjust to the environment hasn't devolved away just yet. You could also buy a wide brimmed sun hat or safari hat, or e.g. a sombrero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a mobile face cooling hat with a portable fan (I'd suggest something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HACfH.jpg)), some ducktape, and a hat (I'd suggest a hardhat). Just tape the fan to the hat in such a way that it's touching facing your face and BAM! Mobile face cooler.

[image]

Comment: Seriously? If I saw people wearing this on the street I will laugh very hard.

Comment: @CaryBondoc Sounds like you're just jealous you don't have a hat fan. I suspect this is going to be really popular in 2016. So make one now! Be a trend starter instead of a follower.

Comment: Haha. Yeah, that would be great!

Comment: Make it look like a life support. >:]

Comment: Or you could just [buy one](https://www.google.com/search?q=hat+with+fan).

Comment: Oh here you go: http://koolbreezesolarhats.com

Answer (score 9):

Keep a wet towel around your neck. Wipe your face from time to time.
*(Nethack fans will do it with #wipe)*

Evaporation of water on your skin will cool your skin. Physical reason is [latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat#Table_of_latent_heats).
[image: Pulse points]

Cooling base of neck has a medical reason ([2009, Han et. al](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2tm289vb)) resulting in cooler body. [Blood vessels near skin](http://lifehacker.com/5571072/know-your-bodys-cooling-spots) transport a lot of blood towards the head and can be cooled by the wet towel. This helps to regulate whole body temperature.

Comment: Yep cooling the base of your neck with a wet wipe or pack of ice will bring down the temperature of the entire body.

Answer (score 2):

An idea similar to Wipqozn's (But real and looks decent)

$9.99 on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C2AQJW) There is assorted colors available.

[image: hat Fan]

Comment: -1 The reviews on that page make it clear that this product doesn't work well at all

Comment: That Disproves your idea as well, -1 to you too then.